# rebuild/refresh my table's PK list - gap in numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have finished all my changes to a database table in sql server management studio 2012, but now I have a large gap between some values due to editing. **Is there a way to keep my data, but re-assign all the ID's from 1 up to my last value?**

I would like this cleaned up as I populate dropdownlists with these values and then I make interactions with my database with the assumption that my dropdownlist index and the table's ID match up, which is not the case right now.

My current DB has a large gap from 7 to 28, I would like to shift everything from 28 and up, back down to 8, 9, 10, 11, ect... so that my database has NO gaps from 1 and onward.

[image]

If the solution is tricky please give me some steps as I am new to SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: Just some questions to better understand what you want to do...Why does it matter that there is a gap in sequence? Do you REALLY want an identity value that was previously deleted to be reused? Are there any foreign keys that reference this primary key column?

Comment: Downvoting without a comment, close vote, or flag is unproductive and doesn't help those that need it.

Comment: @beargle, As mentioned above I populate dropdownlists with these values and my logic assumes that the dropdownlist INDEX matches the tables PRIMARY KEY. These values are never edited by users, they are here simply for selection purposes. A user has a rank value option to choose, and this list simply holds each rank's corresponding name value. That make sense?

Comment: To go on further, my dropdownlist index current has a size of 33, or indexes 1-33. but my database technically has PK's for 1-53, since I have a large gap. Meaning that only keys 1-7 will accurately line up, the rest will be off or will throw errors as no value exists for keys 8-28

Comment: How big is your table? You could always store your data in a temporary table truncate the main table and then insert the data back from the temporary table.

Comment: Or rename your current table to tablename_old, create a new table with the same definition and do an insert into tablename select columns from tablename_old

Comment: @TMNT2014 very small, this is all practice, but as people are mentioning I am starting to realize that tightly-coupling an select index to a PK isn't very wise, so I may just make a new ID colum, or pass a selectlist within my controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are any number of ways to "close the gaps" in an auto generated sequence. You say you're new to SQL so I'll assume you're also new to relational concepts. Here is my advice to you: don't do it.

The ID field is a surrogate key. There are several aspects of surrogates one must be mindful of when using them, but the one I want to impress upon you is,

```
-- A surrogate key is used to make the row unique. Other than the guarantee that
-- the value is unique, no other assumptions may be made concerning the value.
-- In particular, no meaning may be derived from the value as to the contents of
-- the row or the row's relationship to any other row.
```

You have designed your app with a built-in assumption of the value of the key field (that they will be consecutive). Already it is causing you problems. Do you really want to go through this every time you make changes to the table? And suppose a future feature requires you to filter out some of the choices according to an option the user has selected? Or enable the user to specify the order of the items? Not going to be easy. So what is the solution?

You can create an additional (non-visible) field in the dropdown list that contains the key value. When the user makes a selection, use that index to get the key value of the selection and *then* go out to the database and get whatever additional data you need. This will work if you populate the list from the entire table or just select a few according to some as yet unknown filtering criteria or change the order in any way.

Viola. You never have this problem again, no matter how often you add and remove rows in the table.

However, on the off chance that you are as stubborn as me (not likely!) or just refuse to listen to the melodious voice of reason and experience, then try this:

- Create a new table exactly like the old table, including auto incrementing PK.
- Populate the new table using a Select from the old table. You can specify any order you want.
- Drop the old table.
- Rename the new table to the old table name.

You will have to drop and redefine any FKs from other tables. But this entire process
can be placed in a script because if you do this once, you'll probably do it again.

Now all the values are consecutive. Until you edit the table again...

Answer (score 2):

**You should refactor the code for your dropdown list and not the PK of the table.**

If you do not agree, you can do one of the following:

1. Insert another column holding the dropdown's "order of appearance", make a unique index on it and fill this by hand (or programmatically).
2. Replace the SERIAL with an INT would work, make a unique index on the column and fill this by hand (or programmatically).
3. Remove the large ids and reseed your serial - the code depending on your DBMS

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time. If you don't have any foreign key constraints then it should be an easy fix.

Remember a DELETE statement will remove the record but keep the identity seed the same. (If I remove id # 5 and #5 was the last record inserted then SQL server still stores the identity seed value at "6").

TRUNCATING the table will reset the identity seed back to it's original value.

INSERT_IDENTITY [TABLE] ON can also be used to insert the correct data in the correct order if tuncating cannot happen.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tempTable
FROM [TableTryingToFix]

TRUNCATE TABLE [TableTryingToFix];

INSERT INTO [TableTryingToFix] (COL1, COL2, COL3, ETC)
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL2, ETC
FROM #tempTable
ORDER BY oldTableID
```